# Getting taskbar with clock (notification area) on second monitor with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, notification-area

My Windows 10 updated itself this morning and now the notification area (the rightmost part of the taskbar with clock) will only appear on the laptop monitor.  The past several weeks it was happily appearing on an external monitor.

I'm on a Surface 4 with two external monitors (both DisplayPorts).  Monitor 2 is my main monitor and I've extended the display to the other two.  All monitors show taskbars, but the notification area only appears on the Surface.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can mark an accepted answer? :P

Answer (score 50):

You can right click either taskbar, uncheck `Lock all taskbars`, and then drag the taskbar that includes the Notification Center onto the monitor you want it. Afterwards you can recheck the `Lock all taskbars` option if you wish.

I've confirmed that this currently works, but have not seen a way to add the notification center to muliple taskbars.

Comment: At first I thought this wasn't working for me because I didn't get any visual indication to show that I was dragging, but once my cursor was on the other screen, it did work. I just dragged a blank bit of the task bar (i.e. not specifically the notification area).

Comment: This is confirmed to work on win10 2004, some how my taskbar was moved to the secondary monitor and using this method I was able to get it back to the main monitor

Comment: Damnnnn, my answer still helping people over 3 years later brings tears to my eyes. Would be nice if the OP marked it as accepted though lmfao. Glad to hear it helped you @RaptorX

Comment: Thanks bro. It still helps in 2021

Comment: I can happily witness that this still works in 2023 win10. You've been a hero for many.

Answer (score 9):

Set your monitor as main monitor in Display properties, unlock the taskbar,
right click on the taskbar and select properties, you should have a section there that lets you show it on multiple monitors, also lets you select what buttons appear in the other taskbars, accept your changes, then drag the main taskbar to the monitor that you want to show the clock on, then relock it.

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works.